# $ HK $ is a subgroup, can we conclude that $H$ or $K$ is normal in $ HK $

Tags: group-theory

We know that if $HK=KH$, then $ HK $ is a group. Can we conclude that always $ H $ or $ K $ is normal in $ HK $?
if $ H\cap K=1$ is ir true?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take two  proper subsgroups of a simple group which products is whole group.

Comment: Excuse me if their intersection is equal to 1 could you give me an example?

Comment: this anwer is still valid. Write the simple group as sylow product. Then make them coprime.

Comment: Thank you very much I found an example $ H=A_4$ abd $ K=(12345) $. Many thanks

Comment: Many thanks for your helpFor a finite group $ G $ is it true that $ G=P_1P_2....P_k $ where $P_i $ s are different prime numbers?

Comment: $A_5$ is normal in $S_5$ and $(12345) \in A_5$.